# how to generate a calendar for year using SAS

Tags: date, sas, calendar

I want to generate a column(i.e. dates) to save calendar date for a given year
for example:

```
     `dates`
  01jan2019
  02jan2019
  ....
  28jan2019
  01feb2019
  .....
  31dec2019
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you planning to do with this? There might be another way of doing that.

Comment: Any reason you are omitting Jan 29,30,31 ?

Comment: @user667489 these can be useful for Visual Analytics dashboards to improve control performance. It's been a while since I've had to do that though.

Comment: This creates a 'date dimension' that may be useful for whatever you're trying to do. https://gist.github.com/statgeek/9606118

Answer (score 1):

SAS dates are just the number of days since Jan 1st 1960. Use date literals and a do-loop.

```
data dates;
    format date date9.;

    do date = '01jan2019'd to '31dec2019'd;
        output;
    end;
run;
```